# Cannot populate POJO with JSON using Jackson

Tags: jackson

I'm trying to populate a POJO from a JSON that doesn't really match in any way and am having trouble getting this resolved.  I can't change the JSON since it is an external service but I maybe able to modify the POJO if needed.

Below is an example JSON:

```
{"Sparse":[{"PixId":1,"PixName":"SWE","Description":"Unknown"},{"PixId":2,"PixName":"PUMNW","Description":"Power Supplement"}],"Status":0,"Message":null}
```

Below is the POJO:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Pix {
    @JsonProperty("Description")
    private String description;
    @JsonProperty("PixId")
    private int pixId;
    @JsonProperty("PixName")
    private String pixName;


    // getters and setters
}
```

And here is my code to do the conversion:

```
ObjectMapper om =  new ObjectMapper();
om.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
om.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
List<Pix> pixList = om.readValue(pixJson, new TypeReference<List<Pix>>() {});
```

The  pixList contains only 1 element (should be 2 using the JSON above) and all the properties have not been populated.  I'm using Jackson 1.9.9.  Any ideas on how to get this to work?  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create new POJO class for main object which contains the `List<Pix>`. It could looks like this:

```
class Root {

    @JsonProperty("Status")
    private int status;

    @JsonProperty("Message")
    private String message;

    @JsonProperty("Sparse")
    private List<Pix> sparse;

    //getters/setters
}
```

And now your deserialization code could looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

List<Pix> pixList = mapper.readValue(pixJson, Root.class).getSparse();
```

Comment: Although I hate changing the POJO to include unnecessary fields that are irrelevant, the above worked.  Was hoping the ignore properties along with forcing a TypeReference would have done the trick.